# Best auto complete/suggest for a search form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

**I have a rails app that uses the following,**

- rails 3.1,
- ruby 1.9.2,
- mysql,
- sphinx search,
- will paginate,
- thinking sphinx,
- I opted not to use a gem for a simple login, so no devise, no
  authlogic. Login from scratch, using BCrypt for encrypting passwords.
- JQuery.

*Now, this app does nothing but handles a products catalog.
When I say products catalog, not just a simple one. It handles, all the features, categories, brands.*

**There is a master text search functionality on all the product titles and features listed in 2 mysql tables. TITLES and FEATURES. Search is working fine and relevant.**

### We have decided to include auto-complete/auto-suggest in to our app.

### Questions:

---

1. Should I use a gem or build it from scratch?. please give your reason
2. If I should use a gem, which one to use, does that gem is up to date
       and has a forum to support anytime?.
3. We think, auto-complete/suggest on "titles" table would be fine when
       compared to adding auto-complete/suggest on both "titles" and
       "features" tables. Your comments on that?
4. What is it, auto-suggest or auto-complete?

---

*(Like, there is PAT ALLAN and BARRY HUNTER for thinking sphinx and sphinx search,Gosh! its their dedication to support that make users sleep sound)*

I stated the elements of my app in detail, please advice me !

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jqueryui is a great resource.

here is a demo of autocomplete, you can view the source to see how to implement on your server.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

the javascript sends a term=TERM to your controller. Mine is setup like this:

```
def autocomplete
  @movies= Movie.select("id, title").where("title LIKE ?", "#{params[:term]}%").limit(20)
  @hash = []
  @movies.each do |movie|
    @hash << {"label" => movie.title, "id" => movie.id}
  end
  render :json => @hash
end
```

customize to how you see fit.

Comment: LIKE..?.. @Mike, install sphinx search man its amazingly fast. Thanks for your answer. What aboout crowdint/auto-complete?

Comment: @beck03076 LIKE ? does a mysql search looking for a title like the params[:term} with the % acting as a wildcard. Yes thinking sphinx is fast and i love it and do use it just was not using it for this controller. The crowdint autocomplete is the same exact thing, its just wrapped into a gem with some helper methods. I was using that gem for my autocomplete but i ran into some problems displaying the extra values

Comment: So you are saying.. use this..jqueryui ..not the crowdint gem. right?

Comment: no if you should be fine with the crowdint gem. I was just too lazy to figure out how to get custom data to display using the gem plus i wanted to learn about jquery/javascript